# My WordPress plugin wp_enqueue_scripts won't work

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on the following code. I have looked at all the documents regarding wp_enqueue_scripts and wp_register_script I cannot get it my Wp_callApi.js to load.

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: My webservice
Version: 1.4
Description: Calling Webservice with javascript.
Auther: JellyDevelopment
Author URI: http://jellydevelopments.co.za
Plugin URI: http://jellydevelopments.co.za
*/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_Javascript' );
function load_Javascript() {
    wp_register_script('prefix_script_01', plugins_url( 'Wp_callApi.js', __FILE__ ), array ('jquery'), "2.1", true );  
}

//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addMy_script' );

function addMy_script() {
 wp_enqueue_scripts( 'Wp_callApi' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'addMy_script', 10, 1 );

?>
```

Comment: My script file directory is /wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/JellyDevelopments/Wp_callApi.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mutliple errors here. Try this version.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin name: My webservice
Version: 1.4
Description: Calling Webservice with javascript.
Auther: JellyDevelopment
Author URI: http://jellydevelopments.co.za
Plugin URI: http://jellydevelopments.co.za
*/

function load_Javascript() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix_script_01', plugins_url( '/Wp_callApi.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_Javascript' );
?>
```

This will precisely do what you want. It will enqueue a file named Wp_callApi.js to your front end. This file must be residing at the root of this plugin that you write. If you want to add this file to wordpress admin dashboard then you need to change the action. The last line will change to.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_Javascript' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!! you have no idea how much you helped. if i may ask what were the errors my ide doesn't have php tools

Comment: You file should be in wp-content/plugins/my-webservice/ And you should use the hook where you want it.